# QGIS GPS Information Menu Automatically Add Points

Tags: qgis, gps

We are using a Surface Pro 3 with Windows 8.1 64bit, Bluetooth GPS, and QGIS (2.4 standalone download).  We have opened a new QGIS project and are able to connect to the GPS unit within the GPS Information menu.  The map centers on the current GPS location and track points are automatically added to the screen.  Our problem is that the points are not being saved to the point file.  In fact, the track points on the screen just disappear after closing out of the QGIS project.  Below are the steps that we took.  Can anyone please help?

1. Added a point vector file
2. Connect to GPS
3. Opened an editing session for the point vector file
4. Within GPS Information menu checked “Automatically save added features” and “Automatically add points”
   5.We can see the track develop on the screen as we drive.  When we close the editing session, and close out of QGIS, none of the points have been stored in the shapefile.

In a nutshell, we want to be able to automatically add and save points to a point file during an editing session without having to physically press “add point” each time we need to add a point.

Comment: Just a quick guess: Should the trackpoints not rather go into a line shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

The tracking point function in the GPS information pane is meant to create nodes for connecting line segments in either a polyline, or polygon.
When you are finished collecting the nodes you wish connected, you press the Add Line/Polygon button.

When recording in a point layer, you will have to press the Add Point button for each location you wish to record.

Based upon a great deal of experimentation, you can record tracking points for a line layer, and single point locations for a point layer by toggling the active layers. (Other software packages call this function Nesting.) 
In other words, collect tracking points for say a fence line, and collect point locations for the gates along said fence line. You can also deviate from the route you are on and locate a series of different points in different layers, then return to collecting tracking points for the fence line.

To the best of my knowledge, the GPS information pane does not record individual points (Add Point) at the GPS update interval. (1 Hz, 10 Hz, etc.)

You may be able to extract the nodes of the polyline you are creating if you wish to go that route and simply press Add Line when you wish to stop tracking a specific set of features.